# Are there any special server requirements for rendering a .mobi site?

Tags: mobile-website, .mobi

I need to develop a mobi site for a client, do I need a specific server setup for this, or are there any additional server configurations that I need in order to render a mobi site or does it work the same as a normal website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .mobi domain is not different (in terms of setup/configuration) than a .com

Even from a technological point of view, you can develop a mobile oriented application using the web technology (Java, PHP, Python, PHP...) and hardware infrastructure you prefer.

From the developer perspective, there's good instructions for .mobi compliance [here](http://mobiforge.com/starting/story/dotmobi-mobile-web-developers-guide), and [ready.mobi](http://ready.mobi/) is a great and free testing tool to evaluate mobile-readiness using industry best practices & standards.

Comment: I can think about some minor issues regarding the Content-Type you send depending on the device that is browsing your web application, that could be solved by configuration. But you can choose platforms (such as MyMobileWeb in Java) so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

[ready.mobi](http://ready.mobi) is a great tool for testing compliance for this. Also, there's good instructions for .mobi compliance [here](http://mobiforge.com/starting/story/dotmobi-mobile-web-developers-guide).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should check the availability of Javascript in the target platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your server should be able to serve pages with the application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml MIME type, otherwise some WAP browsers wil not render the page correctly (Nokia series 60).