# Widgets and .mobi sites, is this possible?

Tags: widget, mobile-phones, mobile-website

I have a couple of concerns, I'm busy building a normal .mobi site for a client, so basically how I understand this is keep it simply since most phones do not support JavaScript and have a small screen etc. So I build a mobi site using only content and basic links. Now my question is how do mobi widgets work on a mobile site? I've googled and could not find a answer? Is this possible at all? Since these small sites are meant for normal entry level phones and not smartphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.mobi is a domain suffix generally used to identify that the content is specific to mobile devices. It doesn't imply any association with Widgets.

Mobile widgets are generally specific to operating systems, and their definition varies across mobile OS's. Nokia Web Runtime Widgets for example use the webbrowser and provide access to device specific API, but it is native to S60 and needs to be installed on the device. Not what you or your client want here I think.

You have couple of options for developing mobile web sites. Have a look at the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126662/mobile-version-of-my-website-what-design-width-is-optimal/2138673#2138673). It may help point you in the right direction. Search also for questions related to DeviceAtlas, who also provide similar API to WURFL.

Worth also taking a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433163/are-there-any-special-server-requirements-for-rendering-a-mobi-site).

Comment: Thanx Kevin also what I though, thanx for the useful answer